# Using rsync to backup to two locations

Tags: backup, rsync

Please forgive my ignorance, I have searched for an answer but have so far come up blank.

Here's what I want to do:

Use rsync to backup from the fileserver (Ubuntu Server 14.04) to a NAS device. When this backup is complete then run rsync again to a remote server via SSH.

I have a nagging feeling that this won't work properly - something to do with how rsync marks files as already backed up and not changed since last backup.

Am I right to be suspect that this might cause a problem?

Thanks,

Simon.

Comment: I don't think so. `rsync` compares the target location and the source location, not the source location with itself. Otherwise how would those who mirror repositories using `rsync` be able to do so?

Comment: Thanks muru ... that's the sort of reassurance I wanted before starting out - it will take a long time to test once I've written the necessaries so if I was on the wrong track then I'm sure someone would have let me know.

Comment: @muru: please convert your comment to an answer so that people like me who go hunting for unanswered questions find them answered in the comments... :-)

Comment: @Fabby I suspect OP would like it tested, and I am too lazy to do that. If you can run a small test on rsync's behaviour, please feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
   It [rsync] offers a  large  number  of  options
   that  control  every  aspect  of  its behavior and permit very flexible
   specification of the set of files to be copied.  It is famous  for  its
   delta-transfer  algorithm,  which  reduces the amount of data sent over
   the network by sending only the differences between  the  source  files
   and  the  existing  files in the destination.
```

Out-of-the box, without any special parameters, rsync will do *exactly as you need*:

- sync all differences to the NAS *and* sync all differences to the remote SSH server.
- The first time you run it, it will create a full copy on both, and then sync the 2 independently.

*Even when the connection to the remote server is dropped, it will just continue where it left off next time it's invoked.*